# Displaying max number of multitouch pointers supported

Tags: android

I've searched and not been able to find an answer to this question.
I have an app where it is required to know the amount of fingers the device's multi-touch can support up to. Is there any way that I can display the amount of fingers the users device can support. For example HTC Desire - 2, HTC Desire HD - 4 etc.